# What is configuration image zero and one?

Tags: intel-fpga

Currently, I am working in Broadwell-DE based module design.
In this circuit, There is an FPGA (p/n :10M02SCU169C8G )

Please see the configuration user guide added. ( ref page 14)
https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_config.pdf

So there is pin for config_sel ( selecting the configuration image 0/1)

I have gone through the doc and unfortunately I could not get the concept of configuration image 0 and 1.

Please do advice if any one know the concept of config_sel and what should be the default connection?

Thanks
VT

Comment: As a complete guess, I'm going to say that the associated memory chip can hold two sets of programming.

Answer (score 1):

From page 2-3:

> Note: In dual compressed images mode, you can use the CONFIG_SEL pin to select the configuration image

The table on page 2-4 shows the Flash Memory Sectors for multiple Internal Configuration Modes. The first mode (dual compressed image) has a "Compressed Image 1" and a "Compressed Image 0".

When using any of the other 4 modes, the CONFIG_SEL pin connection is irrelevant. Page 3-6 describes the step-by-step to select a different configuration mode.

You should probably want to refer to the tables that start on page 3-18 (pg 50) about image selection. There you can see how CONFIG_SEL pin changes the image to be loaded (from image0 to image1) on "DUAL" configuration image mode.